# UC first all files recursevly

Tags: linux, perl

I need to ucfirst all files recursevly. I found command which ucfirst all files but it doesn't apply for subfolders

```
perl -e 's/\.[^\.]*$/rename $_, ucfirst($`) . $&/e for @ARGV' *
```

how to modify this command for subfolder files also

thanks

Comment: Your `*` shell wildcard will give you all current files. You can use `find` to get all files recursively instead.

Comment: I tried but if I change * to find * doesn't work by some reason

Comment: You need to execute your Perl program as an action from `find`. There should be tons of examples of how to do that around here.

Comment: this "perl -e 's/\.[^\.]*$/rename $_, ucfirst($`) . $&/e for @ARGV' find -name find *" works but again for the top files,ignores subfiles. Maybe need to change perl code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks @simbabque, had to modify line to make it properly working and this is working solution

```
 find . -type f | perl -nE 'if(length $_ > 2) {chomp $_;$o=$_;s{/([^/]+)$}{"/".ucfirst $1}e; rename $o, $_}'
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137930/discussion-between-oleksandr-khavdiy-and-borodin).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find .` to get all files recursively. You can then pipe the list of files into your Perl program.

You need to make some changes in your program, because it currently receives filenames from the command line arguments. If you pipe stuff in, it comes from STDIN. The `-n` flag is useful for that. It implies the loop you have, so you can remove that.

```
find . | perl -ne 's/\.[^\.]*$/rename $_, ucfirst($`) . $&/e'
```

However, your regex does not match any more now, because you don't get `foo`, but `./foo` as the output. You will have to change the regex.

```
find . | perl -nle 'next if -d; $o=$_;s{/([^/]+)$}{"/".ucfirst $1}e; rename $o, $_'
```

This uses a different approach. It saves the original full file path, matches the name of each file after the final slash `/` and replaces that with its `ucfirst`. It then renames. The `-l` removes the newlines at the end of the input, which is equivalent to `chomp`. The `next if -d` is to exclude folders. `-d` takes the topic variable `$_` as its default arg if no arg is supplied, so we can omit it.

```
$ tree
.
├── bar
│   └── barbar
└── foofoo

1 directory, 2 files
$ find . | perl -nle 'next if -d;$o=$_;s{/([^/]+)$}{"/".ucfirst $1}e; rename $o, $_'
$ tree
.
├── bar
│   └── Barbar
└── Foofoo

1 directory, 2 files
```

As [Borodin suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42752126/uc-first-all-files-recursevly/42752605?noredirect=1#comment72623221_42752605), you can also do this shorter version, but you need to have [at least Perl 5.14](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Non-destructive-substitution) because of the `/r` modifier, which makes the substitution return the changed value, instead of changing `$_` and returning success.

```
find . | perl -lne 'rename $_, s{([^/]+)$}{ucfirst $1}er unless -d'
```

Note that you can also build this completely in Perl with a bit more code, and without `find`, but more readable for the future. Take a look at [File::Find::Rule](http://p3rl.org/File::Find::Rule) for it.

Comment: that code doesn't work for any files. Sorry, I don't know perl, I just need ucfirst files but seems in windows is much easy to do that then in linux

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy have you tried working with it to fix it yourself? I didn't run the rename, but it a `print` it worked quite nicely.

Comment: yes tried but no luck so far. I tried to change command to mv, remove "\n".

Comment: @simbabque: Your `find .` is sending newlines through the pipe. Add a `-l` option to the perl command to remove them. You can also drop the slash and use the "non-destructive" option on the substitution `find . | perl -lne 'rename $_, s{([^/]+)$}{ucfirst $1}er'`

Comment: @Borodin please go ahead and edit. I'm on the phone. Funny enough, I just fixed a ten year old bug in Devel::ebug related to -l for my pull request challenge :-)

Comment: @simbabque: I'll leave it to you to change. I'm on my tablet and editing is too much trouble!

Comment: I don't know why that answer topped but its not working correctly. It just ucfirst folders but not the files inside.

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy because it has a good explanation of what's going on, and because the people who vote not all try the code. Your question is vague, you were not specific enough to explain what exactly should happen. Borodin [just asked for more clarification on your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42752126/uc-first-all-files-recursevly/42752605?noredirect=1#comment72637737_4275365). Your question was how to get the files recursively. That's answered. Tell us exact behavior, and we can do more. Better yet, try for yourself and then ask if you get stuck again. :)

Comment: @simbabque, bah, how can be more specific? I wrote that I need and seems you was trying to write the code exactly to my needs. My question was more then specific and I wasn't need some clue but solution, its obviously. And this more then strange if code that work for is downvoted but not working code up voted :)

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy your answer was probably downvoted because it looks like you were replying to me. That's not how we do things here. This is not a forum. It also does not explain why it works. So I can see why someone downvoted it. I didn't vote on it at all yet. However in terms of being specific, you should include the expected output. As Borodin said, do you want to rename folders too? Or only files? If folders are included, you need to go backwards from the leafs up. If not, you need to filter out the folders.

Comment: @simbabque I wrote "I need to ucfirst all files recursevly". And I didn't think that someone see folders too. I would write folders and files? Anyway, I will try to be even more specific if that need, thanks for the tips.

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy folders are files too in Unix. Anyway, you solved it already. You can accept your own answer. If you include more details it might also get a few votes. I will amend this post to exclude folders later.

Comment: @simbabque but there is logical difference between folder and file. Even folder working as a file in UNIX, logically that is folder and you name it folder.
PS.
Why did you remove(if that you) remove comments on my answer below?

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy I cannot remove anything. I'm not a moderator. There were too many comments, and when you accepted the suggestion by the site to move the conversation to chat, they have been automatically moved into that chat.

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy I've updated the answer to exclude folders and added an example.